# Listing Meeting Organizer as not required attendee

Tags: outlook-2010, lync

I would like to know when creating an appointment (meeting) with outlook 2010, is there a way to list myself (as the meeting organizer) as not required attendee?  Reason is my Lync, which linked to my outlook, will show me as "in a meeting" and I would like to not having it shown.

Alternatively, configing in Lync will also do but I can't seems to find the option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just go to Lync's option - Status and select:

I want everyone to be able to see my presence regardless of system settings (override default settings)

That should prevent your Lync status linked with Outlook's schedule